# Show products from a specific category in the product list

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I just want to ask how do I show specific category only in a product list?

```
<?php

include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
$i = 0;

$dynamicList = '<table  border="1" bordercolor="#d6d6d6" cellpadding="10"         
cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
     $id = $row["id"];
     $brand = $row["brand"];
     $product_name = $row["product_name"];
     $pdetails = $row["pdetails"];
     $details = $row["details"];
     $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
     if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
     $dynamicList .= '<tr><td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" title="' . $pdetails . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" height="280" border="0" ><br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a></td>';
} else {
$dynamicList .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" title="' . $pdetails . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" height="280" border="0" ><br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a></td>';
}
$i++;

}
$dynamicList .= '</tr></table>';

?>
```

The category that I want to show is `$comment` with a value of `Best Seller`. I hope this is enough code to understand and help.

Comment: Do u have a table column which holds the information about that which says its a Best Seller ?

Comment: Yes @abhik-chakraborty i have added it in an inventory list (phpmyadmin). I just dont know how to call.

I have a list of products in my php table that says they are best seller


(id 10, product_name Cottonseed, price 550, details Cleansing milk,
category Skincare, subcategory Cleanser, producttype Acne Prevention
comment Best Seller, pdetails Gentle as a cleansing milk)

Comment: I see so where do you want to display ? along  with <br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a>

Comment: I want to replace the if statement of dynamiclist: <tr><td>SHOW BEST SELLER ONLY</td></tr>

Comment: I did not get you can use the following to check if its best seller something as if($row['comment'] == 'Best Seller'){ add your code here }

Comment: it doesnt sort. it is still showing all products when I do this

 if($row["comment"] == 'Best Seller'){
    $dynamicList .= '<tr><td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" title="' . $pdetails . '"><center><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" height="150" width="150" border="0" ></center><br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a></td>';
    }

Comment: Ah so you just want to display all Best Seller no other product right ?

Comment: yes! sorry for confusing

Comment: check my answer this will fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show all best sellers then you can change the query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
```

to

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
where `comment` = 'Best Seller'
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
```

The above will fetch all the best seller products.

You do not need to change anything in the PHP side, the query will sort for you !!